# HTML file saving itself after using table contenteditable

Tags: php, html, file, save

I have an html file with a table and some rows with "contenteditable", after changing some things in the table I want to save it either with a button or just after I finished changing the text. Not locally, but so I can access this html page on another device with the saved data from before.

Is there a way to do this without a Database, javascript or php? If not my first choice would be php but I couldn't figure it out either.

I tried saving the whole changed html content to itself but I somehow didn't get it to work. I tried sending the whole html content to a "save.php" file which reads the POST data and saves the data to the .html file itself but nothing worked.

Is this possible with just html?

Comment: Let me regurgitate to make sure I understand. You would like to be able to change the content of HTML elements on one device and have it propagate those changes to another device? Sorry for the graphicness of the phrasing, but I figure if I can't spit out what you're trying to explain, then either I didn't understand it well enough or there's a disconnect somewhere.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You need to write a server script to do it, and send the changes to the server either by putting a form around the table or using AJAX.

Comment: Well, I mean you can save changes locally, but if you want the changes to show up when the page is accessed from another computer you will certainly need server-side code (and ideally a database too).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this without a DB the server side change with PHP seems like good idea. You can't do it without some kind of server side script if you want to access it anywhere but locally. You have a few choices, but it is possible.

You could have a script that takes your POST data and saves it to a text file and another script that gets the data from the text file for an AJAX request from your .html file, or as you were trying, re-write your html page content with PHP.

You could do it in a single page with a text file to save your data to. Put the table on a php page and do all the read/writing to and from the text file before you start showing the table. Just set the form action to be the same page.

There may be better answers around separation of concerns and good programming practice, but the key point is what you are doing is possible.
Next time you get stuck, post your code here instead of trashing it and people can give you more specific feedback.